# How to send an object as a parameter for a POST request in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, post

I need to bind parameters in an object and pass the object as a POST request to receive a successful piece of information from an API.

```
{
  customer = {
    "auth_token" = "";
    "device_id" = 3e708bf1a49cdd06;
    "email_address" = "abc@xyz.in";
    name = abc;
    number = 1234567890;
    "resend_token" = true;
   };
}
```

This is the object that I need to send along with the post request. But when I convert it into a string and post it, the entire object becomes the key and the value becomes `nil`. It gets posted as `{"{customer.....}=>nil}`.

The object should be posted as

```
    {"customer:
{"auth_token":"","device_id":"3e708bf1a49cdd06","email_address":"abc@xyz.in",
"name":"abc","number":"1234567890","resend_token":"true"}}
```

This my current attempt:

```
    NSArray *objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"",@"3e708bf1a49cdd06",@"abc@xyz.in",@"abc",@"1234567890",@"true", nil];

    NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"auth_token",@"device_id",@"email_address",@"name",@"number",@"resend_token", nil];

    NSDictionary *tempJsonData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

    NSDictionary *finalJsonData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:tempJsonData,@"customer", nil];

    NSData *temp = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:finalJsonData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    NSString *postString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:temp encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSError *error = nil; NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

A lot of the code used here was used without a proper understanding and directly taken from other StackOverflow answers, so please excuse any bad programming practice.

How can I do this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the required by the API for the encoding? It looks like they need JSON content so I'd try with first making sure it is set as the request _body_ and not as a parameter and specify `text/json` or `text/html` for `Content-Type`

Comment: I just checked. The API requires data to be raw and not JSON. How can I make a POST request by sending a raw string to the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below code.Instead of converting data to string set it as HTTPBody like

```
// Create the request.
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

// Specify that it will be a POST request
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

// This is how we set header fields
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


// Convert your data and set your request's HTTPBody property

NSArray *objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"",@"3e708bf1a49cdd06",@"abc@xyz.in",@"abc",@"1234567890",@"true", nil];

NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"auth_token",@"device_id",@"email_address",@"name",@"number",@"resend_token", nil];

NSDictionary *tempJsonData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

NSDictionary *finalJsonData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:tempJsonData,@"customer", nil];

NSData *temp = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:finalJsonData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];


request.HTTPBody = temp;


// Create url connection and fire request
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
NSError *error = nil; NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Comment: * `request.HTTPBody = temp` was the only change. This worked perfectly, thanks.
`[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];` was the key that I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the sample code for sending a POST request to server.

```
-(void)doRequestPost:(NSString*)url andData:(NSDictionary*)data{
    requestDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:data];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSString *jsonString=[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];

    NSLog(@"Request Object:\n%@\n",data);
    NSLog(@"Request String:\n%@\n",jsonString);

    NSMutableURLRequest *theReq=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
    [theReq addValue: @"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theReq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theReq addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[jsonString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theReq setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theReq delegate:self];
}
```

May this help lot and resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"id=%d&restaurant_name=%@", restaurnt_Id, _rest_NameTxt.text];
    NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:EDIT_RESTAURANT_API];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"APPLICATION/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"APPLICATION/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

_responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

## pragma mark - connection methods

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [_responseData setLength:0];
    [_responseCityData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [_responseData appendData:data];
    [_responseCityData appendData:data];
}
-(BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return YES;
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [COMMON showErrorAlert:@"Internet Connection Error!"];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responseString = [responseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
    NSLog(@"%@", responseString); 
}
```

Make your task in connectionDidFinishLoading method